# String Labels for dependent axis in silverlight bubble chart

Tags: silverlight, bubble-chart

I'm creating a bubble chart using silverlight. The dependent axis takes only int values but I need to label both the axes with strings. I browsed a lot and couldn't find proper answer. There is no proper API for toolkit chart also. Can someone please tell me how setting the axes labels works and what all the steps to do that? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using BubbleSeries.DependentRangeAxis. Inside the tag, LinearAxis.AxisLabelStyle should be used with a binding component and a converter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also line type chart with bordercolour 0. It will appear like bubble type chart without restrictions of bubbleTypeChart.